# Camel: stopping the route inside the Splitter

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I have the below route and in the second when clause, i have a list of events generated and using the split to process each individual event using a eventbean. In the bean i have a producer template which will send the message to the endpoint. The issue i am having is in case if the endpoint is not resolved or it's not reachable an exception is thrown but the route is still processing all the events.But what i want is i need to stop the route or not allow the other events to process once the exception is thrown. so i am using the   inside the split and if an exception is thrown i want to stop the route or come out of split.I am not sure if this is the right way to handle my problem but trying to see if this works.

```
<route id="routeid">
          <from uri="{{queue.in}}"/>
          <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${body} contains 'somedata'</simple>
                    <to uri="bean:somebean?method=process" />
                </when>
                <when>
                    <simple>${body} contains 'somedata' || ${body} contains 'somedata' || ${body} contains 'somedata'</simple>
                    <to uri="bean:somebean?method=process" />
                    <filter>
                        <simple>${body.size} > 0</simple>
                        <split>
                            <doTry>
                                <simple>${body}</simple>
                                <to uri="bean:eventbean" />
                            <doCatch>
                                <exception>com.exception.EndpointNotFoundException</exception>
                                <handled>
                                    <constant>false</constant>
                                </handled>
                                <to uri="direct:addToErrorNotificationQueue" />
                                <stop/>
                            </doCatch>
                            </doTry>
                        </split>
                    </filter>
                </when>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use route level onException as follows,

```
<route id="routeid">
  <from uri="{{queue.in}}"/>
  <onException>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
    <to uri="direct:handleException"/>
    <handled>
        <constant>false</constant>
    </handled     
  <onException>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
</route>
```

So that any exception occurs any where in the route it caught bu onException and remaining code will not execute.

You can put global level onException aswell.

Hope its helps!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to catch exceptions inside `<split>` then put the whole `<split>` inside `<doTry>`

```
<doTry>
    <split>
        <simple>${body}</simple>
        <to uri="bean:eventbean" />
    </split>
    <doCatch>...</doCatch>
</doTry>
```